# How to remove time from datetime index string

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, datetime-format

My questions is how to remove the time part from the string of an index. I am importing a csv with minute stock data and the code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f'/Volumes/Seagate Portable/S&P 500 List/AAPL.txt')

df.columns = ['Extra', 'Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)
df.set_index('Dates', inplace=True)
df = df.between_time('9:30', '16:00')
df.drop(['Extra', 'Open', 'High', 'Volume', 'Low'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).agg({'Close':'last'})
df.index[0]
```

This modifies the dataframe to find the last close price of the trading day. The output to this is:

```
Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

So my issue is that I want to remove the time (00:00:00) from the string. I dont want to do something like:

```
` df.index = df.index.date)`
```

or

```
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).dt.date
```

This is because then the output of `df.index[0]` will be: `datetime.date(2020, 1, 2)` which is not what I am looking for. So what I tried was

```
for df_dates in df.index:
    string_df = f"{df_dates}"
    split_string_df = string_df.split(' ')
    df_dates = split_string_df[0]
    df.index[df_dates] = df_dates
```

This gives me the error `TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`
So what I am looking for a code that will remove the time portion of the string in a way that after I can index out `df['2020-2-12']` rather than `df[datetime.date(2020, 1, 2)]` (I am not sure, put I am assuming this means to modify the display rather than the actual index, but I dont know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
indexes =[]
for df_dates in df.index:
    string_df = f"{df_dates}"
    split_string_df = string_df.split(' ')
    df_dates = split_string_df[0]
    indexes.append( df_dates)
df.index = indexes
```

The problem is you tried to modify the indexes by index by calling `df.index[<something>] = <otherthing>` because the index list is immutable and have to be modified at whole..

Comment: This worked thank you! I didn't think of that, I appreciate your help

Comment: With pleasure ...!

Comment: Yes sorry I was going to right when you put up the answer, I just had to wait the minute because it wont let you accept the answer right away, and I forgot to come back. My apologies